# Parse 2d int array to List of BubbleDataPoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, chart.js, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an algorithm which makes use of a grid which is implemented via an int[,] in C#. I would like to graph the output in Blazor using the Bubble chart of blazor chart.Js. Preferably I would like to create separate datasets depending on the value of the int. 0 = empty/ignore, 1 = particular object type, 2 = particular object type.

I'm having an issue with picking out the data and converting it to the BubbleDataPoint(x,y,r) which the chart expects. I would like the x,y to correspond to the array index e.g. graph[1,1] = 1 would be bubbledatapoint(1,1,1) etc. I implemented an IEnumerable method in my class so that I could use foreach or .select on the int values but not sure how to get the array indices out.

```
public IEnumerable<int> GridValues()
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < grid.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; x < grid.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    yield return grid[x,y];
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so for anyone interested I went with this method. I initially wanted to avoid looping over the array until I realised that 2D arrays don't implement IEnumerable and I was doing a half-way method but then just decided to go with this.

```
public IEnumerable<BubbleDataPoint> GridToDataPoints()
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < grid.GetLength(0); x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < grid.GetLength(1); y++)
                {
                    yield return new BubbleDataPoint(Convert.ToDouble(x), Convert.ToDouble(y), Convert.ToDouble(grid[x, y]));
                }
            }
        }
```